# Add limit in group_concat

Tags: mysql, group-concat

My mysql query like :

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(scorecard_id  ORDER BY scorecard_id DESC) as scorecard_id 
FROM scorecard 
WHERE partner_id = 121 AND client_id = 15
```

It returns me data like :

```
65,64,63,62,61,60,39,38,37,36,35,34,33,32,31,30,29...
```

I want to add limit in **group_concat** so that it returns first 2 values i.e:

```
65,64
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe enclosing by a subquery would do:

```
SELECT 
GROUP_CONCAT(t.scorecard_id) AS scorecardId
FROM 
(
    SELECT
        scorecard_id
    FROM scorecard
    WHERE
        partner_id = 121
    AND client_id = 15
    ORDER BY scorecard_id DESC 
    LIMIT 2
) AS t;
```

Comment: Thanks Kamil, But as I have to join 3 tables, and GROUP_CONCAT with almost each tables,


Like : 
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(scorecard_id  ORDER BY scorecard_id DESC) as scorecard_id, GROUP_CONCAT(t2.category_title) as category_title 
FROM scorecard as t1
LEFT JOIN scorecard_Category as t2 ont1.scorecard_id=t1.scorecard_id
WHERE t1.partner_id = 121 AND t1.client_id = 15